# On Visual Studio load, AWS Toolkit posts get instance metadata and gets timeout (502). How do I disable that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015

When I have the AWS Toolkit installed, it takes a long time for Visual Studio (2015 update 2) to open.

Why? Because (as I saw using Fiddler) it's posting to 169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document like 9 times, and timing out every time.
I found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) article which explains what that's all about.

But how do I turn it off? I really don't want to wait for so long for Visual Studio to load every time I open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying SDK that the toolkit uses had a bug, fixed last week, where it was attempting to always fetch instance metadata to try and determine the AWS region (even when not running on an EC2 instance). I don't recall the version of the toolkit being built on that SDK version but it's possible.

A colleague posted an updated toolkit (1.9.6.21) this evening for an unrelated change - can you install this and see if you still see an issue? If so I'll take a look when I get into the office.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try out the latest and let you know soon.

Comment: 1.9.6.21 ? I downloaded from aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/ and what I installed appears in "Uninstall or change a program" as version 3.9.378.0

Comment: the first time opening Visual Studio (after installing 3.9.378.0) took forever (like maybe 5 minutes) but after that opening it seems pretty fast, and I don't see those requests in Fiddler anymore.

Comment: Without the Toolkit, I believe Visual Studio was taking 2 seconds or so to open. Now that i've installed this version, it's taking about 8 seconds